# Implementing entities sync efficiently with sync tokens

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to implement synchronization of entities in my system between back-end and front-end. As an example I want to use the approach that was used in *Google Calendar API(using sync tokens)*.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

I try to find out what is architecture background here to implement such a functionality.

Here what I was thinking of:

Once user request the changes we create a token if there is no token in request or use the one that was sent if there is one in request. Token will be stored to DB and it will have the date of creation. Each time user requests system with token, I create a new one and return it with the entities that were modified, created after the date that is stored in current token. New token will have a today's date. Deleted entities are tracked within additional table(tombstones with ids).

Is that a best way to implement this, or there might be something else behind the scene?

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be no esoteric discussion of calendar api synching architecture in the docs, only the [Synchronize Resources Efficiently](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync) page which you're already aware of. Not sure if it helps, but try this [topic on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-would-be-a-good-architecture-for-a-system-that-has-a-sync-feature-like-Evernote-or-Dropbox-to-work-on-and-offline-with-mobile-and-web).